# Ready-to-use NPAPI-Plugin to launch external application?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi

I need to launch an external application from a Google Chrome extension. I need to pass a few parameters from javascript, wait until the external application is done and then use its output in javascript.

I did some reading and this should be possible using an NPAPI plugin (I only care about Windows so far).

Since my C/C++ got very rusty over the years and my requirements are quite simple I was wondering if somebody knows about a ready-to-use NPAPI DLL that does just the one thing I need: Launch an EXE with several parameters and return its output?

I tried Google of course, but didn't find anything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be rather easy to write such a plugin in C++ with Firebreath. Writing a NPAPI plugin from scratch can be tricky, but luckily Firebreath abstracts away most of the details and makes it much easier.

As a plus, if you base the plugin on Firebreath, in addition to NPAPI on Windows you pretty much get free support for NPAPI on Mac/Linux and ActiveX on Windows.

http://www.firebreath.org

Comment: Yeah; you can get a plugin that builds up and running with FireBreath in about 5 minutes if you already have visual studio and cmake installed, then you just need to find the API calls for launching a process and add it to the API.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there really is no way around setting up a C/C++ build environment ;)